# Что можно узнать из лога пользователя?

Tags: сеть, логирование, ip-address

Какой максимальный объем информации можно получить, анализируя отчет следующего вида?

```
Start End Sif SrcIPaddress SrcP DIf DstIPaddress DstP P Fl Pkts Octets

0111.00:00:09.956 0111.00:00:09.956 2 aa.aa.aa.aa 4445 65535 bb.bb.bb.bb 135 6 2 1 64 
0111.00:04:30.928 0111.00:04:30.928 2 cc.cc.cc.cc 28243 65535 dd.dd.dd.dd 67 17 0 1 341 
0111.00:04:50.908 0111.00:04:50.908 2 ee.ee.ee.ee 6000 65535 ff.ff.ff.ff 2222 6 2 1 40
```

aa.aa.aa.aa и т.п. ip - адреса

Возможно ли узнать о тех ресурсах, которые посещал пользователь?

Comment: Ну по ip вы можете узнать какие сайты там расположены. Но для некоторых хостеров на одном ip может оказаться и 100 разных сайтов и какой конкретно из них вы по этой информации разумеется не поймете

Comment: Можно ли автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Ну при большом желании может быть и можно. bing.com может искать по ip, можно сделать программу, которая будет к нему обращаться и парсить ответ. ну по крайней мере пока MS вас за это не забанит. И смысл для меня все равно не ясен. что даст знание что пользователь заходил на "какой то из этих 100 сайтов". Логи DNS гораздо информативнее, чем информация о трафике.